# 'User' object has no attribute 'get' when trying to get user data in update profile form

Tags: django, django-allauth

im new in django. i'm trying to get user data in the update form.
here is my code:

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', default='default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user}'
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'uk-input', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'uk-input', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'uk-button uk-button-default uk-button-medium uk-width-1-1', 'type': 'file'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

views.py

```
@verified_email_required
def profile_view(request):
    u_form = UpdateUserForm(request.user)
    p_form = UpdateProfileForm(request.user.profile)
    title = 'Profile Page'
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    context = {
        'title': title,
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

and i get this error:
['User' object has no attribute 'get'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hibuK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the instance through the `instance=...` parameter. By using the first one, you pass the `request.user` and `request.user.profile` as `data` parameter (so as if it was a GET or POST querydict):

```
@verified_email_required
def profile_view(request):
    u_form = UpdateUserForm(instance=request.user)
    p_form = UpdateProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    title = 'Profile Page'
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    context = {
        'title': title,
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```